# При обращении к массиву по индексу "undefined"

Tags: javascript

Создаю массив из массивов данных полученного из CSV файла. При обращении к конкретному массиву по индексу выводит "undefined".

```js
let csvarray = [];
let client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', 'xls-test.csv');
client.onload = (el) => {
  let rows = client.responseText.split('\n');
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    csvarray.push(rows[i].split(';'));
  }
}
client.send();
```

Comment: `console.log(csvarray)`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 0):

Проверку производил после тела onload вот и "undefined", если проверять в теле то всё хорошо, а лучше не onload, а onreadystatechange.